# Authorization and Token Validation with WCF Service

Tags: wcf, security, authentication, authorization, wcf-security

I am working on an internal test framework in which one of the requirements is to be able to allocate a resource that can be used within a test (e.g. allocate a physical PC that will be used as part of the test).  This resource has a **WCF** service running on it and the test talks to it using a proxy.

As a part of the framework, I will like to add some level of authorization where after allocating a resource, a token is retrieved and presented to a service running on the resource and must be validated by the resource's service.

We've come up with 2 main options for this:

**1.** **Federated security** - the proxy that talks to the resource gets a token from a Security Token Service and presents it to the resource's service which validates it.  This seems to be the cleanest solution, but the main issue is revocation of the token after the device is released. One option is to have the token have a timeout of a few mintues and the worst case is the resource is unused for a few minutes - but this is less than ideal.

**2.** **Validation with token service in each call** - in this solution, the resource service uses the token service to validate the token (instead of just validating it itself using the public key as in solution #1).  This solves the issue of revocation, but it seems like tons of overhead to validate it with another service for each call.

What do you all think? Which option is better? Is there an option 3 (4,5, etc.)?
Thanks!